# need help in creating excel-vba function

Tags: function, excel, vba

My problem: It works fine when I call it in a SUb. But it gives a high jump in the value of "pf" I want to give a condition that pf is always less than dpdlold...I tried different ways but nothing worked..

code starts from here:

```
Public Function pf(p, pwf, xf, PI, tau, n, k, wg, Hf, wf, Bg, dpdlold, mug, Bg_p, mug_p)

Dim i, j As Integer

Dim error As Double

Dim pj As Double

Dim pj1 As Double

Dim pj0 As Double

Dim e As Double

j = 100

i = 0

error = 1000

pj0 = dpdlold

pj = pj0

e = 0.001


    While (error > e) And (i < j)
        qgr = FrGas(tau, n, k, wg, Hf, wf, pj, mug_p)
        pj1 = (p - pwf - 2 * qgr / PI) / xf
        error = Abs(pj1 - pj)
        pj = pj1
        i = i + 1
    Wend
        pf = pj


End Function
```

Comment: thanks I always make this mistake......

Comment: pf is always less than dpldld except when ;lkjwe mod rwerewrew is twice 987wewse3. Seriously though, between your brief description and briefer variable names, you're preventing at least one person from trying to solve your problem. Maybe try simplifying it to an example that you and others could test?

Comment: "I tried different ways"… I see nothing that shows what you tried. If you could be a little bit more explicit about your "jumps", and your "tries", we might be able to help better.

Comment: ufff....I tried to use a condition  in while "And pj>dpdlold"---- that doesnot calculate any new value of pj .... If I enclose the "while to wend " statement in a "If pj>dpdlold " even than it does not work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about changing your loop to something like this:

```
While (error > e) And (i < j)
    qgr = FrGas(tau, n, k, wg, Hf, wf, pj, mug_p)
    pj1 = (p - pwf - 2 * qgr / PI) / xf
    error = Abs(pj1 - pj)
    if pj1 > dpdlold Then pj1 = dpdlold
    pj = pj1
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Now, if `pj1` gets too big, it will be "clipped" to the value of `dpdlold`. If it hits the limit twice, the "error" in successive estimates will be zero and it will stop.

With the limited information you gave it's the best I can do…

Comment: by the way i learned one thing that if statement can be written without endif......thanks